# How to Add Redux object as a Parameter with Props in React Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-functional-component

I have an object "user" in reduxReducer and i want to use it in a functional component.

I use this object by using mapStateToProps as following:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({

   login: state.login,

});
```

Follwing is the component in which i wanted to use this object.

```
const ProfilesAdministration = (props, { login: { user }}) => {

   // Code Here

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({

   login: state.login,

});

export default connect(mapStateToProps , null)( ProfilesAdministration );
```

Please Help.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should access it from props. Redux connect argument [mapStateToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapstatetoprops-state-ownprops-object) will add the result from your selector to the components props:

```
const ProfilesAdministration = (props) => {
   // or const user = props.login.user
   const { user } = props.login
   // Code Here

}
```

Connect makes your component like having additional props from the redux store.